# How to get RF/NV items from Android, Qualcomm devices?

Tags: java, android, c++, c, qualcomm

Is there any way to capture Layer 1/3 RF related information’s or to get NV items from Android, Qualcomm devices?

I found some parameters from android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony) and also i tried Qualcomm NV Tool but didn’t worked.

Then I used busybox and run **AT** commands to get some information’s, [echo "AT+COPS=?\r" | busybox microcom -t 5000 /dev/smd11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhAB8.png).

Please advice..

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course, but you can't use the AT command interpreter for that because the Layer 1/2/3 data feed is enormous. Qualcomm devices uses anther format to connect and send commands to modem. What you find as AT is just a very limited wrapper around that. What you need are the *Qualcomm* proprietary tools known as `QXDM` and `QCAT`, these also have a Python API and tons of other features. (A third tool called `QPST` is used to connect the device to these tools.) The list of Qualcomm's NV items are included in those tools and the upper range of those are slightly different for every modem, and which is for OEM customization. [HERE](https://github.com/dl12345/qcn/blob/master/nv.txt) is a very old list with some of those.

And [here](https://github.com/fgsect/scat) is a more convenient tool to get diagnostic data from QC modems.